# Hyper-V Internal Switch IP addresses (and networks) keep changing

Tags: hyper-v

I run several Hyper-V guest VMs on my Win 10 workstation.
Unfortunately, quite frequently, my saved RDP connections stop working.

Sometimes only the IP address changes in the same network (e.g. `ip 192.168.27.* netmask 255.255.255.240`). But other times I even find myself (or the guest VM) in a completely different network `172.x.x.x`.

`OS: Win 10 rel. 1903`

How can I stop this erratic behavior -.-
If it didn't change networks as well I would have simply set up static IP addresses for my guest VMs.